# Perfect numbers, please help

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Perfect numbers:6, 28, 496, 8128, ...

There is some interesting patterns, I just want to share it with you guy and ask some questions about.

(1)

$1+2+3=6$, perfect number 6 has 3 terms

$\frac{3-1}{2}=1$

$$6=1\cdot2\cdot3$$

(2)

$1+2+4+7+14=28$, has 5 terms

$\frac{5-1}{2}=2$

$$28^2=1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot7\cdot14$$

(3)

$1+2+4+8+16+31+62+124+248=496$, has 9 terms

$\frac{9-1}{2}=4$

$$496^4=1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot8\cdot16\cdot31\cdot62\cdot124\cdot248$$

This is resembling the factorial numbers.

I want to know does this pattern continue for all perfect numbers? If it does how you go about justifying it.

Comment: It's not clear what "this pattern" means, though as Henry points out in answering, there is a characterization of even perfect numbers in terms of Mersenne primes, and existence of any odd perfect number is an open problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can say :

- even perfect numbers are of the form $n=2^{p−1}(2^p − 1)$ where $p$ and $2^p-1$ are prime
- $n$ then has $2p-1$ divisors other than $n$, and the product of those divisors is $n^{p-1}$

The basis for the first of these is the [Euler-Euclid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem) and the second is a simple derivation from the first

Comment: These primes $2^p-1$ are known as the [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).

Comment: Also, there is no known odd perfect numbers

Answer (score 3):

That's not a coincidence. The divisors of any (non-perfect-square) number $n$ are paired together: any time you have a divisor $d$, you have $n/d$ which is the other divisor, in some sense, his brother.

For example, for $n=496$
$$1 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 8 \cdot 16 \cdot 31 \cdot 62 \cdot 124 \cdot 248 =$$
$$=(2 \cdot 248) \cdot (4 \cdot 124) \cdot (8 \cdot 62) \cdot (16 \cdot 31)= 496^4$$

How is that the power is $4$? That's because there are $9$ divisors, and you throw away the trivial divisor $1$ (whose brother is $496$). The remaining $8$ divisors are paired, and you get $4$ pairs of numbers whose product is $496$.

Comment: So all even perfect numbers work in this way.

Comment: I like your answer, nice!

Comment: Yes. Actually this is a property of all non-perfect-squares.